# How to hide an edge of vis.js using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, vis.js

I want to hide nodes and all it dependent edges inside angularjs controller. I'm using angular-vis.js. The code I have can only hides nodes but it not hiding edges.

```
$scope.hideSelection = function() 
{ 
    $scope.data.nodes.update([{id: $scope.selectedNode.toString(), hidden: true}]); // this part is working fine
    $scope.hiddenNodes.push($scope.selectedNode);

    if ($scope.selectedEdges.length > 0){
       $scope.selectedEdges.forEach(function(edgeId){
           $scope.data.edges.update([{id: edgeId.toString(), hidden: true}]); // When it comes here it not doing the update as it did on nodes
           $scope.hiddenEdges.push(edgeId);
       });
    } 
}
```

Here is the link to my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N639ZxuIjvTO1MidM2D2?p=preview) to see full example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem that you pass edges to `$scope.data` not as vis.DataSet:

```
$scope.data = 
{
  nodes: new vis.DataSet(nodes),
  edges: edges //  <==
};
```

==>

```
 $scope.data = 
{
  nodes: new vis.DataSet(nodes),
  edges: new vis.DataSet(edges) // <==
};
```

[ http://plnkr.co/edit/1H1RBZr9KUPrVhAqT6fX ]